# Function in function returning "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' "

Tags: python, function, int, range, nonetype

I'm trying to get a moving avarage in a DataFrame (df).

The code that I have written is doing exactly what I want but this is just for 5 rows. see below:

```
def movingavarage (df,column, avg,remark):
    for i in range(0, df.shape[0] - avg):
        df.loc[df.index[i + avg],'SMA_5'] = np.round(((
        df.iloc[i + 0, column] +
        df.iloc[i + 1, column] +
        df.iloc[i + 2, column] +
        df.iloc[i + 3, column] +
        df.iloc[i + avg - 1, column]) /
        avg),1)

    return output(df, remark)
```

I would like to do the same for 200 rows and I don't think I need to copy past code "df.iloc[i +',i,', testcolumn] +" 200 times.

So created a function that helps me with the middle bit of the code. See below the code and the output:

**input:**

```
def loc (max):
    for i in range (0, max, 1):
        if i != max - 1:
            x = print ('df.iloc[i +',i,', testcolumn] +')
        elif i == max - 1:
            x = print ('df.iloc[i +',i,', testcolumn] ')
    return x

loc (4)
```

**output:**

```
df.iloc[i + 0 , testcolumn] +
df.iloc[i + 1 , testcolumn] +
df.iloc[i + 2 , testcolumn] +
df.iloc[i + 3 , testcolumn]
```

This works, but how do I get these two combined?

I tried multiple options but it gives me contstantly the error:

```
File "/functions.py", line 45, in movingavarage2
    loc (4) +
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The combined code looks as follows:

```
def movingavarage2 (df,column, avg,remark):
    for i in range(0, df.shape[0] - avg):
        df.loc[df.index[i + avg],'SMA_5'] = np.round(((
        loc (4) +
        df.iloc[i + 4, column])/avg),1)

    return output(df, remark)
```

Comment: loc (4) + "space" causes the error

Comment: `x = print ('df.iloc[i +',i,', testcolumn] ')` - `print` returns None. So x is None. So loc(4) is None

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to do the moving avarage: rolling avarage from pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html